# Statically linking SQLite with DMD (Windows x86)

Tags: windows, sqlite, d, dmd

I've tried to statically link with sqlite3 without success. I'm using the 'etc.c.sqlite3' header, and the sqlite3 amalgamation. To create the .lib file I've tried both VC++ and MinGW-gcc, both of these compile the source file successfully - but they both generate COFF object format (optlink, which DMD uses, works with OMF). After reading tons of posts on 'digitalmars.D', I've tried several different solutions.

[objconv:](http://www.agner.org/optimize/#objconv)

- tried to convert lib file created with GCC, resulted in undefined symbols such as __divdi3 and __muldi3, wasn't able to solve this.
- Also tried this to convert the sqlite3.o file to *.obj, and then use digitalmars 'lib.exe' - unsuccessful as well
- Attempting objconv on a VC++ generated lib fails because: "SQLite.lib is an import library"

[implib:](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/implib.html)

- If I download the precompiled DLL from sqlite.org and use implib, it generates a lib file, but the name mangling does not seem to match, because even though I link with the static library, I still receive the same sqlite errors (e.g undefined symbol `_sqlite3_open`, `_sqlite3_errmsg`, `_sqlite3_close`...

[coffimplib:](http://www.digitalmars.com/ctg/coffimplib.html)

- If I use coffimplib on the VC++ created library file, the program generates a nearly empty file (~2KB) which only contains garbage (i.e no symbols at all and mostly just 'null' values).
- If I do the same with the GCC created library, coffimplib complains about "not an import library" and no converted library file is generated.

If I use DMC to compile the sqlite3 amalgamation, the compilation fails complaining about *tons* of errors. So here I am, stuck in nowhere, does anyone have any ideas or tips what might solve this?

NOTE: I do not want to use a DLL, but statically link with sqlite (for executable size concerns).

Comment: What errors do you get with the C compiler?

Comment: Tons and tons. It would require way too much to fix them all, with all types of errors (e.g illegal cast, unknown identifer)

Comment: I downloaded and tried DMC; it appears the errors are caused by bugs in the Windows header files shipped with DMC.

Comment: Is there anything that could be fixed or is it too extensive? My errors did not seem to be related with windows headers though...

Answer (score 3):

Try using `implib` with `/system` switch.

Comment: That actually did the trick! Although this created an import library, not a static library, so the executable still depends on the whole sqlite dll when it only uses ~5 of its functions

Answer (score 1):

On Windows you're better off with dlls. Saves you a lot of headaches.

Work on x64 support is underway which will leverage COFF + VC's linker I think.
This will hopefully change the awkward situation.

Edit: If you really need static libs you may try out Unilink, which is able to link OMF and COFF files together:
ftp://ftp.styx.cabel.net/pub/UniLink

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm using at the moment, but not all libraries support shared ones (e.g dyncall) and the application size jumps when producing small executables (relative to the dependencies)

Comment: Unilink sure is an interesting choice! I'll check it up (shallow documentation though). Do you have any idea when x64 support for COFF will be available?

Comment: Phobos compiles but doesn't work yet.
https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/commits/master

Answer (score 0):

Why you simply do not compile and link the SQLite C code with your D application? I guess that will save your from library-related headaches.

Of course a good alternative is to compile the SQLite static library with DMC, and use it with your D project by simply doing: `dmd -of myproggy myproggy.d somefile.d libsqlite.lib`

Comment: Dmc fails to compile (see my comments) the SQLite amalgamation. And if I want to link, the objects need to be in OMF format, and that's the root of my problem!