# How to use SQLite library in D language program on Windows?

Tags: dll, sqlite, d

How to use **SQLite3** library in **D** language program on Windows?

I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6664109/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-use-sqlite-in-d-program-on-ubuntu) with Ubuntu, but it didn't work in my case.

```
import std.stdio, std.string, etc.c.sqlite3;

void main () {
  sqlite3* db;
  auto ret = sqlite3_open (toStringz("mydb.s3db"), &db);
  writeln (ret);
}
```

As I assume, the **sqlite3.d** is some kind of header to the real SQLite3 library. I've got an **sqlite3.dll**, but I have no idea about how to link it with my program. `pragma` works only with lib formate (like `pragma(lib, "sqlite3")`).

Maybe I should use the **SQLite** sources, but how is it possible to compile it together with **D** code? Or is it better to find some way to convert **dll** to **lib**?

What is a general method to solve such problems in **D**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Or is it better to find some way to convert **dll** to **lib**?

Yes. From the question [Statically linking SQLite with DMD (Windows x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443193/statically-linking-sqlite-with-dmd-windows-x86), just run the .dll file through `implib` with the `/system` switch (linking with the resulting .lib file will still result in dynamic linkage and a dependency on the .dll file).

Comment: Yes, now `pragma` works. Thank you!
I used `implib` from the [Digital Mars Basic Utilities](http://ftp.digitalmars.com/bup.zip).

Answer (score 3):

You can also compile the sqlite source (with modification) using  Digital Mars C copmiler which will then give you an object file you can statically link.

Comment: I have no idea of how to modify source code from *Sqlite* official site to make *Digital Mars C compiler* work with it. Looks like none trivial task for me.

Comment: Agreed, it is not trivial. You can grab SQLite as a single source file and fix compiler errors until Digital Mars C accepts it. The changes needed aren't for a C novice, but they also weren't too bad either.